# Unable to change values in JTable with custom TableModel using setValueAt

Tags: java, swing

I'm coding small schedule of visits.
It bases on JTable with custom TableModel extending AbstractTableModel as shown on image below.

The problem is that it is possible to initializate Table and to get desired look - but after data change using `setValueAt()` there is no change in appearance of Table. Button click takes sample String and sets fields in columns "Type" and "State" at 9:00 (more precisely depending on given hour and date of reservation)

What is more I'am able to insert new row at the end of table but cannot make visible existing value update. Tried many solutions but sadly without result.
I would be very grateful for every suggestions.

[image]

**Working code illustrating the problem:**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ModelTest {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable tablePendingVisits;
    private PendingVisitModel pendingVisitModel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPanePendingVisits;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ModelTest window = new ModelTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ModelTest() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 407);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnChangeValue = new JButton("Change value at 9:00");
        btnChangeValue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                refreshTableModel();
            }
        });
        btnChangeValue.setBounds(63, 308, 305, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnChangeValue);

        tablePendingVisits = new JTable();
        scrollPanePendingVisits = new JScrollPane();
        pendingVisitModel = new PendingVisitModel();

        tablePendingVisits.setModel(pendingVisitModel);
        scrollPanePendingVisits.setBounds(63, 36, 305, 246);
        scrollPanePendingVisits.setViewportView(tablePendingVisits);

        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPanePendingVisits);
    }

    public void refreshTableModel(){
        String[] sampleString = {"9:00", "Bobby", "Tables"};

        // search for row with 9:00 and replace values in given columns
        for (int i = 0; i < pendingVisitModel.getRowCount(); i++) {

            if( sampleString[0].equals(pendingVisitModel.getValueAt(i, 0)) ) {   // Change row values when both hours are equal 
                pendingVisitModel.setValueAt(sampleString[1], i, 1);             // Change at type column
                pendingVisitModel.setValueAt(sampleString[2], i, 2);             // Change at status column      
            }
        }
    }
}

// Custom TableModel
class PendingVisitModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String[] columnNames = {"HOUR", "TYPE", "STATE"};
    private Vector<String[]> data = new Vector<String[]>();

    public PendingVisitModel() {

        for(int i = 8; i<15; i++) {
            data.add(new String[]{i+":00", "-", "Free"} );
            data.add(new String[]{i+":15", "-", "Free"} );
            data.add(new String[]{i+":30", "-", "Free"} );
            data.add(new String[]{i+":45", "-", "Free"} );
        }
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public String getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        String[] temp = data.get(row);
        if(temp.length > 0 && col < 3)
            return temp[col];
        else
            return null;
    }

    public void setValueAt(String[] value, int row, int col) {
        String[] temp = data.get(row);
        temp[col] = value[col];

        data.set(row, temp);
        fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
    }

    public void insertRow(String[] value) {
        data.add(value);
        fireTableRowsInserted(data.size(), data.size());
    }

    public void clearRows(){
        data.clear();
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void removeAllEntry(){
        data.clear();
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getColumnClass(int colNum) {
        return String.class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between `public void setValueAt(String[] value, int row, int col) {` and `public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {`

You can test this by using the `@Override` annotation, for example...

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(String[] value, int row, int col) {
```

Generates a compiler error, where as

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
```

does not.

So changing the `setValueAt` method to...

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    if (value instanceof String) {
        String[] temp = data.get(row);
        temp[col] = value.toString();

        data.set(row, temp);
        fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
    }
}
```

Worked just find for me

Also, you really should avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

As noted in the comments, you could also use `public void setValueAt(String value, int row, int col) {` (no override annotation) and your code would work, but I wouldn't call the method `setValueAt` as that generates confusion (as you've discovered) and precludes the scenarios where all you have is an instance of `TableModel`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Only after I got into the IDE and tried running it :P

Comment: Note that it would actually work if the method took a String as first argument, because the OP doesn't edit the table: it calls setValueAt() from the refreshTableModel() method, with a String as argument. But I simply wouldn't name the method that way, to make it obvious that it's not an override of the standard setValueAt() method.

Comment: @JBNizet True, but I prefer to work with the available contract where possible. I can think of better ways of providing custom update methods for custom object structures and would generally avoid using method signatures which "look" similar to the implemented contract if possible, but that's just me :P

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent plenty hours trying to find the solution. What is interesting I tried also changing `setValueAt()` arguments to match Override requisitions but without result - maybe i done it wrong.
Anyway - maaany thanks!

Comment: @MadProgrammer I disagree. To me, this makes it strange, and less safe: the model is not editable, but it overrides setValueAt(): why? You should only able to store Strings in the cells, but setValueAt() takes an Object as argument, and ignores it if it's not a String: why? With an updateCellValue(String newValue, int row, int col) method, everything would look clearer and safer to me.

Comment: @user3689007: lesson to learn: always try to use the `@Override` annotation if you *think* that you should be overriding a method.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, agreed, I'd avoid using `setValueAt` as the method signature, which would make it more clear and reduces the confusion as to which method is actually been called. Personally, I still prefer to use `setValueAt` as it's available in the core contract and commonly known (and if the model is made editable, the functionality is already available), again, this is my preference. Normally, I also provide `update` and `add` methods (where the functionality is required for the model) which work with the underlying data structure.